# How does sprintf_s avoid buffer overflow issue

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Visual Studio prompts me to replace `sprintf` with `sprintf_s`, instead of `snprintf`.

`sprintf_s` does not require a length parameter, how does it avoid buffer overflow issue?

Comment: There are template versions that can deduce the size if it is possible from the `buffer` parameter. If that fails you need to provide the size. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=msvc-160 This has an example to show when it will deduce the size and when it will not. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/secure-template-overloads?view=msvc-160

Comment: If you are using `sprintf_s()` that was introduced in C11, the second argument is the size of the string buffer.   Microsoft also specify a non-standard templated version in C++, which accepts an array of `char` as the first argument, where the size is a template parameter.    The latter cannot be passed a `char *` (since the size cannot be deduced).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 versions. One template version which tries to deduce the size of the buffer and one where you pass the size.

```
int sprintf_s<_Size>(char (&_Dest)[_Size], const char *_Format, ...)
int sprintf_s(char * _DestBuf, size_t _SizeInBytes, const char *_Format, ...)
```

If the first one cannot be deduced, you will have to pass the size yourself

So this:

```
char buf[100];

sprintf_s(buf, "%d", 1);
```

Will instantiate a function template

```
sprintf_s<100>();
```

This will generate a compiler error:

```
char *buf = new char[100];

sprintf_s(buf, "%", 1);
```

And you have to use the other version to make it compile:

```
sprintf_s(buf, 100, "%d", 1);
```